# Which is the most optimized way to display an image?

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, frontend, pagespeed

Optimization in terms of page speed and page size.
First method is showing the image as a background of a div instead of in an img tag:

```
<div style="background:url("image-url.jpeg") no-repeat;background-size:cover;max-width:350px;max-height:350px;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

Second is the normal img tag way:

```
<img src="image-url.jpeg" width=350 height=350 alt="" />
```

Or anyone has a better way to display image.

Thank you.

*Disregarding SEO benefits

Comment: it's a lot easier to dynamically load images in markup rather than some styling language. furthermore, the image tag is there for a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer here : https://buildawesomewebsites.com/html-img-vs-css-background-image/

Imo, I'll go with the `img` tag, but I'll improve your code : If you want to improve perfs, you could use 'srcset' attributes with your `img` tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images and load smaller images for smaller devices.

In addition, you can use lazy load with `img` tag easily